# Understanding Angular data binding

Tags: angular

While reading [Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html), I came across this (emphasis mine)

> Angular processes all data bindings ***once per JavaScript event cycle***, from the root of the application component tree through all child components.

Please explain in as much detail as possible what this means? Especially what is "once per event cycle"?

Comment: You should probably raise a documentation issue on their [project](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues) if you feel it's lacking in information

Comment: May it be referring to [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I think it refers to any change or event triggered(Like changing input field ).Once any change occurs it starts from top to bottom.
you can learn more here 
https://vsavkin.com/change-detection-in-angular-2-4f216b855d4c#.a3ggxt9hl

Comment: I don't think if this should be considered as one possibility of what event cycle is. Since, there's actually no cycles in JS native events.

Comment: i mean 
events are emiited on change &     -------------->
from parent change is propagated <---------------
https://angular.io/resources/images/devguide/architecture/parent-child-binding.png

Comment: report it to the community(https://github.com/angular/angular/issues). They can give some insight. I am also bit confused :(

Comment: Oh got it.. Actually this might be it.